# Is it ok to delete the /srv directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, filesystems, kubuntu

Is it okay to remove the srv$ directory in Kubuntu 20.04

There seems to be no files contained inside and it will clear up the structure.

after research I found that it was very much up to what I want with the system.

Comment: With sparce memory and using linux on a vm on a pc (win 10) it is tempting to clean up and remove non usefull files and directories. So far I am only planning on using linux for programming.

Comment: You can safely remove `/srv`.

Comment: I would be curious to understand the profit you expect gaining from this. A couple of bytes ? Speeding up the lookup in the / dir by less than one nsec ?

Comment: I have actually read that srv is good for shared files for groups - like music and films

Comment: `man file-hierarchy` is a good starting point for questions like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubuntu uses `dpkg` to manage packages.  `dpkg -S <path>` will tell you why that path exists as long as it was created by a package installation.

Here are some examples:

```
$ dpkg -S /srv
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /srv

$ dpkg -S /var/www
apache2: /var/www
```

On my system, no package 'owns' `/srv`.  That means no software installed with `apt` should break if I delete `/srv`.  By contrast, `/var/www` is owned by `apache2`.  If I delete `/var/www`, then `apache2` may encounter problems.

However, this only applies to software installed with the system's package manager.  If you rely on something installed with `sudo make install`, then `dpkg` may give you a false negative.  This is one of the many reasons I avoid installing unpackaged applications.

Another place to check for the usage of `/srv` is in your local configuration.

```
$ cd /etc
$ grep -r /srv
passwd:ftp:x:130:139:ftp daemon,,,:/srv/ftp:/usr/sbin/nologin
schroot/schroot.conf:#directory=/srv/chroot/sid
schroot/schroot.conf:#btrfs-source-subvolume=/srv/chroot/btrsnap/sid-snap
schroot/schroot.conf:#btrfs-snapshot-directory=/srv/chroot/btrsnap/snapshots
schroot/schroot.conf:#directory=/srv/chroot/squeeze
schroot/schroot.conf:#directory=/srv/chroot/lenny
schroot/schroot.conf:#file=/srv/chroot/lenny.tar.gz
schroot/schroot.conf:#directory=/srv/chroot/lenny
```

Here, I can see in `passwd`, I have a system user called `ftp` which uses `/srv/ftp` as a home directory.  If I delete `/srv/ftp`, then I may not be able to use my home FTP server.  However that directory is empty, and my `vsftp` settings don't use that directory, so in my case, this would be fine to delete.

I can also see `/etc/schroot/schroot.conf` refers to `/srv`. Reading the file, I can see it's only in the context of an example configuration.  Therefore I know it's also safe to delete here.